# Runtime EXception on re-compile the code in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I've created app.It working fine.

When i've changed some code and compile, it throws "Runtime EXception."

After i've deleted *.dmp file. Its working fine.

Everytime i compile it throw the exception. i delete *.dmp file and re execute.

Pls help me what is the problem and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my experience this error is connected to changes in data structures you save/load from/to PersistentStore.

If you have stored object with a particular structure, and after that you change your object structure, you will get exception upon loading this object from the persistent store.

Removing dmp files cleans your simulator persistent store and your app works fine.
But with old, non-compatible objects stored in dmp file (simulator persistent store) you get the exception.

Comment: Hi friend. thank u. I use persistennt object in my app. u r correct. I think thats the errro occur.

Comment: you told that with old, non-compatible objects stored in dmp file (simulator persistent store) you get the exception.  What should do error don't occur another time.

Comment: Do not know exactly what is going on in your app. Just note that, if you have changed persistable object structure (added/removed fields to class) then you need to remove dmp files before starting updated application. Otherwise your app will try to apply old data to new object structure upon loading and will fail.

Comment: Thank u for ur info. i'm only added a string "Accept" to the persitence objecte when user press accept button. Nothing to add or delete field in persistence object. I modify only in another class.